# undeletable "permanent File" Android 11 phone

Tags: files, delete, javascript

I have this file:

/storage/emulated/0/Tones/test1/test2/test3/test4/brooke-shields,-a�os-80.jpg

Cannot delete. I get a <java.lang.illegalargument> response when I try to delete using several different file managers. My phone is unrooted. Tried through javascript, termux, iShredder, and others. Have tried to understand the black diamond with the question mark, but unclear what it truly is. Am a real novice, so have patience.

Any suggestions on how to delete this file.

Comment: Have you tried an alternative file manager like Solid Explorer, or a similar tool, to delete or rename the file?

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [How to delete miscoded file in Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/254064/44325)

Comment: I did try several different file managers, not specifically Solid Explorer. I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: Solid Explorer did not work. Cannot delete file. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: As per related/possible dupe, I got the same result with Termux as in the question. Says file does not exist....but it's there.

Comment: Can you just delete the entire directory? Move anything you want out of it first...

Answer (score 0):

play with `find` until you get the single line with (1) result.

```
~ $ find -L /sdcard -mindepth 6 -type f -name 'brooke-shields*80.jpg' -print
```

add the `-delete` flag to delete result(s)

Answer (score -1):

- Rename the file and check if you can delete it. Also, have you tried the same with adb?

```
adb shell rm /storage/emulated/0/Tones/test1/test2/test3/test4/brooke-shields,-a�os-80.jpg
```

Comment: It won't let me change file name, I can't move it, I can't copy it, I can't delete it. Per iShredder, it's a "permanent file." Don't want to Factory Reset, but might be my only option. Have ordered a new phone, exactly the same as the one I have (other issues prompted that change), but am concerned that backed up files will contain same undeletable file. Tried several different file manager apps, was suggested to us Solid Explorer. Will try that. Thank you for responding.

Comment: Solid Explorer did not work. Cannot delete.

Comment: I have not tried that, nor do I have any experience with that, but it's worth a shot. Hopefully I'm smart enough to figure it out. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll let you know.

Comment: adb seems to require the use of two (2) Android phones or a PC. I currently don't have access to either one. Not sure if I will be able to utilize adb.

Comment: apps cannot access the app-specific directories that belong to other apps, therefore adb is recommended

Comment: @JimmyB: Yes, you will need to use a Windows, Mac or Linux computer.